# Ruined all permissions in ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, server, file-permissions, plesk

Accidentally i rewrote all folders permission from root.

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /​
```

Just for example. Luckily i have another server. So i started fix all permissions manually one by one. And now everything seems work fine except for one thing: php can't write files.

I have a suggestion that some php or apache process have wrong permissions.

So symptoms:

```
The stream or file "/var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Yes. I'm sure that files have correct permissions. Because this recursive process was not so fast to override `/var` folder too. At least some domain still untouched. So i checked it out.

Maybe it would be helpful to know that i use plesk. Because some `.sock` files could be located there.

Comment: Just out of interest, what is the output of `ls -l /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/storage/logs/laravel.log`?

Comment: @miknik `-rwxrwxr-x 1 client_1019 psacln 131613358 Dec  2 19:16 storage/logs/laravel.log` and highlighted with green.

Comment: and webserver is running as user www-data?

Comment: @miknik no user is `client_1019` exactly. www-data was just for example. Everything did work before with current rights. I'm sure i just broken something in apache

Comment: Look in httpd.conf file and check user and group for apache is correct

Comment: @miknik yes, `SuexecUserGroup "client_1019" "psacln"` but at the same time a have tons of error `Warning: SuexecUserGroup directive requires SUEXEC wrapper.` after `service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what i did but it works now. I hope one day it could be useful for someone too.

Just run script if you use plesk

[`/usr/lib/plesk-9.0/install_suexec`](https://pastebin.com/C7hQNrC7)

So in the we could say i just reinstall script.